# Change iteration type to Sprints

Tags: azure-devops

​If I create a new project and select the **Agile** process, my user stories will be grouped in iterations Eg "MyProject/**Iteration 1**".

However, If I create the project using **Basic process** and after the project has been created, changes the process to Agile I can group my user stories by Sprint Eg "MyProject/**Sprint 1**".

The latter is what I want, however as the process was set to Agile when the project was created (not by me), I'm trying to figure out how to change it to use Sprints as default?

**Side note:**

1. I cannot create a new project as I lack privileges
2. I cannot create a new process as I lack privileges
3. I cannot change to another process because I've already created a bunch or user stories
4. Although I can create sprints manually, I want it to be default.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi wmmhihaa Are the answers below helpful?If you have any questions,please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#activate), we can know that iteration and sprints represent the same concept in the agile process.

> Define Iteration Paths (aka sprints) and configure team iterations

So if you want to visually use Sprints as the default, you can add a new iteration named Sprint in team configuration, or change the name of the existing iteration to the Sprint style. Then set it as Default iteration. As shown in the following figure:

[image]
[image]

Because your current project is already Agile process, the initial display must be MyProject/Iteration 1. If you want to display like MyProject/Sprint 1, you have to modify it later.

There are two ways to change the display: changing the process or manually modifying it. According to your Side note, obviously neither is feasible.

If you really want Sprints as default in agile process project without any manual modification, you could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without changing the Process of your project.